# PHP equivalent of send and getattr?

Tags: php, oop, reflection, getattr, method-dispatch

If Ruby gets invited to a party and brings:

```
foobarobject.send('foomethod')
```

.. and Python gets invited to the same party and brings:

```
getattr(foobarobject, 'foomethod')()
```

.. what does PHP have to bring to the party?

**Bonus question:** If Ruby and Python got jealous of PHP's party-favors, what English terms would they search for in PHP's documentation in order to talk about it behind PHP's back?

Comment: The two are different: the Ruby version invokes the method; the Python version returns a bound method.

Comment: +1 for the creative way to phrase the question :)

Comment: @Miles: the question is now modified by adding paren to the python version.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786412/what-is-the-ruby-equivalent-of-pythons-getattr

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP brings this:

```
$foobarobject->{"foomethod"}();
```

... and the coke and chips.

**EDIT**:

Although the term for the above is [`variable variables`](http://www.php.net/language.variables.variable) there is nothing specifically talking about doing it to an object in the manual. However, you can achieve the same thing with [`call_user_func`](http://www.php.net/call_user_func):

```
call_user_func(array($foobarobject, "foomethod"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using variable to hold the method name. Pretty much the same as Paolo's first example, but maybe not so obvious unless you know about it.

```
$method = "foomethod";
$foobarobject->$method();
```

You also got the [Reflection classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php).

```
$method = new ReflectionMethod('Foobar', 'foomethod');
$method->invoke(null);
```