# What is & How to use getattr() in Python?

Tags: python, function, built-in, getattr, class-attributes

I read an [article](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/getattr.html) about the `getattr` function, but I still can't understand what it's for.

The only thing I understand about `getattr()` is that `getattr(li, "pop")` is the same as calling `li.pop`.

When and how do I use this exactly? The book said something about using it to get a reference to a function whose name isn't known until runtime, but when and why would I use this?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Attributes as strings? First-class functions?

Comment: I think my problem is understanding the concept of getattr(). I still don't understand its purpose.

Comment: @Terence doesn't my answer make things clearer ?

Comment: @Alois, your answer definitely cleared some of my doubts, but I still can't fully understand what getattr() is for.

Comment: @S.Lott, I did. The documentation only had the definition so I was kind of confused about its usage. I understand getattr now after reading more about it though.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786412/what-is-the-ruby-equivalent-of-pythons-getattr

Comment: Technically, `getattr(li, "pop")` isn't the same as _calling_ `li.pop`, which would be `li.pop(<arguments>)`. `getattr(li, "pop")` is the same as `li.pop`, though.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

`getattr(object, 'x')` **is completely equivalent** to `object.x`.

There are **only two cases** where `getattr` can be useful.

- you can't write `object.x`, because you don't know in advance which attribute you want (it comes from a string).  Very useful for meta-programming.
- you want to provide a default value. `object.y` will raise an `AttributeError` if there's no `y`. But `getattr(object, 'y', 5)` will return `5`.

Comment: Am I incorrect in thinking that the second bullet point is inconsistent with opening statement of the answer?

Comment: @skoh: well, actually, the opening statement mentions `getattr` with two parameters (which is equivalent), and the 2nd bullet mentions getattr with 3 parameters. Even if it was incosistent though, I would probably leave it, emphasis is more important.

Comment: u lost me at "because you don't know in advance which attribute you want (it comes from a string)".....

Comment: @UlfGjerdingen: think of javascript. `o.x` is equivalent to `o['x']`. But the second expression could be used with any `o[some_string]` that could be decided at runtime (eg, from user input or object inspection), while in the first expression, `x` is fixed.

Comment: @blue_note and what is `object.x`

Comment: That's the attribute access of the object,  just like in any object oriented language

Comment: To revive a necro, another use case is when the identifier contains an illegal character like `.` or `-` (as I am dealing with now). `getattr(obj, 'some.val')` will work where obj.some.val will not.

Comment: Or rather than containing an illegal character, the attribute name could be a reserved word. To pre-empt the question, both this case and the punctuation case would happen either due to `setattr` having been used previously, or by hacking the object's `__dict__` directly. This can happen implicitly when using `types.SimpleNamespace` or `argparse.Namespace`.

Comment: Does it work inside a class function like getattr(self, local_functionname)?

Comment: @JürgenK.: of course, `self` behaves just like any other object, the only difference is that it's passed automatically

Comment: so 'self' as first argument doesn't need to be given?

Comment: @JürgenK.: not sure what you mean by "given". it automatically appears as an additional first argument when you call a method of an object, like `this` in eg java/c++, only shown explicitly. Regardless, that's general python behavior, unrelated to `getattr`

Answer (score 355):

Objects in Python can have attributes -- data attributes and functions to work with those (methods). Actually, every object has built-in attributes (try `dir(None)`, `dir(True)`, `dir(...)`, `dir(dir)` in Python console).

For example you have an object `person`, that has several attributes: `name`, `gender`, etc.

You access these attributes (be it methods or data objects) usually writing: `person.name`, `person.gender`, `person.the_method()`, etc.

But what if you don't know the attribute's name at the time you write the program? For example you have attribute's name stored in a variable called `attr_name`.

if

```
attr_name = 'gender'
```

then, instead of writing

```
gender = person.gender
```

you can write

```
gender = getattr(person, attr_name)
```

Some practice:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)

>>> class Person():
...     name = 'Victor'
...     def say(self, what):
...         print(self.name, what)
... 
>>> getattr(Person, 'name')
'Victor'
>>> attr_name = 'name'
>>> person = Person()
>>> getattr(person, attr_name)
'Victor'
>>> getattr(person, 'say')('Hello')
Victor Hello
```

[`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) will raise `AttributeError` if attribute with the given name does not exist in the object:

```
>>> getattr(person, 'age')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'age'
```

But you can pass a default value as the third argument, which will be returned if such attribute does not exist:

```
>>> getattr(person, 'age', 0)
0
```

You can use `getattr` along with [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) to iterate over all attribute names and get their values:

```
>>> dir(1000)
['__abs__', '__add__', ..., '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_bytes', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real', 'to_bytes']

>>> obj = 1000
>>> for attr_name in dir(obj):
...     attr_value = getattr(obj, attr_name)
...     print(attr_name, attr_value, callable(attr_value))
... 
__abs__ <method-wrapper '__abs__' of int object at 0x7f4e927c2f90> True
...
bit_length <built-in method bit_length of int object at 0x7f4e927c2f90> True
...

>>> getattr(1000, 'bit_length')()
10
```

A practical use for this would be to find all methods whose names start with `test` and [call them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code).

Similar to [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) there is [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) which allows you to set an attribute of an object having its name:

```
>>> setattr(person, 'name', 'Andrew')
>>> person.name  # accessing instance attribute
'Andrew'
>>> Person.name  # accessing class attribute
'Victor'
>>>
```

Comment: So it seems to me that `getattr(..)` should be used in 2 scenarios: 1. when the attribute name is a value inside of a variable (e.g. `getattr(person, some_attr)`) and 2. when we need to use the third positional argument for the default value (e.g. `getattr(person, 'age', 24)`). If I see a scenario like `getattr(person, 'age')` it seems to me that it is identical to `person.age` which leads me to think that `person.age` is more Pythonic. Is that correct?

Comment: @wpcarro both `person.age` and `getattr(person, "age")` are idiomatic to Python, so hard to make the case one is more Pythonic  than the other.

Comment: "Readability counts". Certainly `person.age` is better than `getattr(person, "age")`. I makes sense to use `getattr` when you have attribute name in a variable.

Answer (score 124):

For me, `getattr` is easiest to explain this way:

**It allows you to call methods based on the contents of a string instead of typing the method name.**

For example, you cannot do this:

```
obj = MyObject()
for x in ['foo', 'bar']:
    obj.x()
```

because x is not of the type `builtin`, but `str`. However, you CAN do this:

```
obj = MyObject()
for x in ['foo', 'bar']:
    getattr(obj, x)()
```

It allows you to dynamically connect with objects based on your input. I've found it useful when dealing with custom objects and modules.

Comment: This is a pretty straight forward and precise answer.

Comment: what is `object.x`

Comment: @develarist The asker didn't have an example for me to base my answer off of, so `MyObject`, `obj`, and `x` (Class def, class instance and attribute respectively) are just examples/mockup data where you should fill in your own classes and attributes that you want to access. `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` are often used as placeholders in linux/unix/foss docs.

Comment: operator.methodcaller( ) is designed to do the same as in this example, calling a method defined with strings. I kind of prefer the implementation in the example.

Answer (score 45):

A pretty common use case for `getattr` is mapping data to functions.

For instance, in a web framework like Django or Pylons, `getattr` makes it straightforward to map a web request's URL to the function that's going to handle it.  If you look under the hood of Pylons's routing, for instance, you'll see that (by default, at least) it chops up a request's URL, like:

```
http://www.example.com/customers/list
```

into "customers" and "list".  Then it searches for a controller class named `CustomerController`.  Assuming it finds the class, it creates an instance of the class and then uses `getattr` to get its `list` method.  It then calls that method, passing it the request as an argument.

Once you grasp this idea, it becomes really easy to extend the functionality of a web application:  just add new methods to the controller classes, and then create links in your pages that use the appropriate URLs for those methods.  All of this is made possible by `getattr`.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a quick and dirty example of how a class could fire different versions of a save method depending on which operating system it's being executed on using `getattr()`.

```
import os

class Log(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.os = os.name
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """ look for a 'save' attribute, or just 
          return whatever attribute was specified """
        if name == 'save':
            try:
                # try to dynamically return a save 
                # method appropriate for the user's system
                return getattr(self, self.os)
            except:
                # bail and try to return 
                # a default save method
                return getattr(self, '_save')
        else:
            return getattr(self, name)

    # each of these methods could have save logic specific to 
    # the system on which the script is executed
    def posix(self): print 'saving on a posix machine'
    def nt(self): print 'saving on an nt machine'
    def os2(self): print 'saving on an os2 machine'
    def ce(self): print 'saving on a ce machine'
    def java(self): print 'saving on a java machine'
    def riscos(self): print 'saving on a riscos machine'
    def _save(self): print 'saving on an unknown operating system'

    def which_os(self): print os.name
```

Now let's use this class in an example:

```
logger = Log()

# Now you can do one of two things:
save_func = logger.save
# and execute it, or pass it along 
# somewhere else as 1st class:
save_func()

# or you can just call it directly:
logger.save()

# other attributes will hit the else 
# statement and still work as expected
logger.which_os()
```

Answer (score 8):

Other than all the amazing answers here, there is a way to use `getattr` to save copious lines of code and keeping it snug. This thought came following the dreadful representation of code that sometimes might be a necessity.

**Scenario**

Suppose your directory structure is as follows:

```
- superheroes.py
- properties.py
```

And, you have functions for getting information about `Thor`, `Iron Man`, `Doctor Strange` in `superheroes.py`. You very smartly write down the properties of all of them in `properties.py` in a compact `dict` and then access them.

**`properties.py`**

```
thor = {
    'about': 'Asgardian god of thunder',
    'weapon': 'Mjolnir',
    'powers': ['invulnerability', 'keen senses', 'vortex breath'], # and many more
}
iron_man = {
    'about': 'A wealthy American business magnate, playboy, and ingenious scientist',
    'weapon': 'Armor',
    'powers': ['intellect', 'armor suit', 'interface with wireless connections', 'money'],
}
doctor_strange = {
    'about': ' primary protector of Earth against magical and mystical threats',
    'weapon': 'Magic',
    'powers': ['magic', 'intellect', 'martial arts'],
}
```

Now, let's say you want to return capabilities of each of them on demand in `superheroes.py`. So, there are functions like

```
from .properties import thor, iron_man, doctor_strange


def get_thor_weapon():
    return thor['weapon']


def get_iron_man_bio():
    return iron_man['about']


def get_thor_powers():
    return thor['powers']
```

...and more functions returning different values based on the keys and superhero.

With the help of `getattr`, you could do something like:

```
from . import properties


def get_superhero_weapon(hero):
    superhero = getattr(properties, hero)
    return superhero['weapon']


def get_superhero_powers(hero):
    superhero = getattr(properties, hero)
    return superhero['powers']
```

You considerably reduced the number of lines of code, functions and repetition!

Oh and of course, if you have bad names like `properties_of_thor` for variables , they can be made and accessed by simply doing

```
def get_superhero_weapon(hero):
    superhero = 'properties_of_{}'.format(hero)
    all_properties = getattr(properties, superhero)
    return all_properties['weapon']
```

NOTE: For this particular problem, there can be smarter ways to deal with the situation, but the idea is to give an insight about using `getattr` in right places to write cleaner code.

Answer (score 4):

```
# getattr

class hithere():

    def french(self):
        print 'bonjour'

    def english(self):
        print 'hello'

    def german(self):
        print 'hallo'

    def czech(self):
        print 'ahoj'

    def noidea(self):
        print 'unknown language'


def dispatch(language):
    try:
        getattr(hithere(),language)()
    except:
        getattr(hithere(),'noidea')()
        # note, do better error handling than this

dispatch('french')
dispatch('english')
dispatch('german')
dispatch('czech')
dispatch('spanish')
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes use `getattr(..)` to lazily initialise attributes of secondary importance just before they are used in the code.

Compare the following:

```
class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n_calls_to_plot = 0

    #...
    #A lot of code here
    #...

    def plot(self):
        self.n_calls_to_plot += 1
```

To this:

```
class Graph(object):
    def plot(self):
        self.n_calls_to_plot = 1 + getattr(self, "n_calls_to_plot", 0)
```

The advantage of the second way is that `n_calls_to_plot` only appears around the place in the code where it is used. This is good for readability, because (1) you can immediately see what value it starts with when reading how it's used, (2) it doesn't introduce a distraction into the `__init__(..)` method, which ideally should be about the conceptual state of the class, rather than some utility counter that is only used by one of the function's methods for technical reasons, such as optimisation, and has nothing to do with the meaning of the object.

Answer (score 3):

Quite frequently when I am creating an XML file from data stored in a class I would frequently receive errors if the attribute didn't exist or was of type `None`.  In this case, my issue wasn't not knowing what the attribute name was, as stated in your question, but rather was data ever stored in that attribute.

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hair = None
        self.color = None
```

If I used `hasattr` to do this, it would return `True` even if the attribute value was of type `None` and this would cause my ElementTree `set` command to fail.

```
hasattr(temp, 'hair')
>>True
```

If the attribute value was of type `None`, `getattr` would also return it which would cause my ElementTree `set` command to fail.

```
c = getattr(temp, 'hair')
type(c)
>> NoneType
```

I use the following method to take care of these cases now:

```
def getRealAttr(class_obj, class_attr, default = ''):
    temp = getattr(class_obj, class_attr, default)
    if temp is None:
        temp = default
    elif type(temp) != str:
        temp = str(temp)
    return temp
```

This is when and how I use `getattr`.

Answer (score 3):

Another use of getattr() in implementing a switch statement in Python. It uses both reflection to get the case type.

```
import sys

class SwitchStatement(object):
    """ a class to implement switch statement and a way to show how to use gettattr in Pythion"""

    def case_1(self):
        return "value for case_1"

    def case_2(self):
        return "value for case_2"

    def case_3(self):
        return "value for case_3"

    def case_4(self):
        return "value for case_4"

    def case_value(self, case_type=1):
        """This is the main dispatchmethod, that uses gettattr"""
        case_method = 'case_' + str(case_type)
        # fetch the relevant method name
        # Get the method from 'self'. Default to a lambda.
        method = getattr(self, case_method, lambda: "Invalid case type")
        # Call the method as we return it
        return method()

def main(_):
    switch = SwitchStatement()
    print swtich.case_value(_)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: I like this answer but please fix the small typos

Answer (score 3):

**setattr()**

We use **setattr** to add an attribute to our class instance. We pass the class instance, the attribute name, and the value.

**getattr()**

With **getattr** we retrive these values

For example

```
Employee = type("Employee", (object,), dict())

employee = Employee()

# Set salary to 1000
setattr(employee,"salary", 1000 )

# Get the Salary
value = getattr(employee, "salary")

print(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this example is self explanatory. It runs the method of first parameter, whose name is given in the second parameter.

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self):
      pass
   def MyMethod(self):
      print("Method ran")

# Create an object
object = MyClass()
# Get all the methods of a class
method_list = [func for func in dir(MyClass) if callable(getattr(MyClass, func))]
# You can use any of the methods in method_list
# "MyMethod" is the one we want to use right now

# This is the same as running "object.MyMethod()"
getattr(object,'MyMethod')()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also clarifying from https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/getattr

```
class Person:
    age = 23
    name = "Adam"

person = Person()
print('The age is:', getattr(person, "age"))
print('The age is:', person.age)
```

The age is: 23

The age is: 23

```
class Person:
    age = 23
    name = "Adam"

person = Person()

# when default value is provided
print('The sex is:', getattr(person, 'sex', 'Male'))

# when no default value is provided
print('The sex is:', getattr(person, 'sex'))
```

The sex is: Male

AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'sex'

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in Python2.7.17

Some of the fellow folks already answered. However I have tried to call
getattr(obj, 'set_value') and this didn't execute the set_value method, So i changed to getattr(obj, 'set_value')() --> This helps to invoke the same.

Example Code:

Example 1:

```
    class GETATT_VERIFY():
       name = "siva"
       def __init__(self):
           print "Ok"
       def set_value(self):
           self.value = "myself"
           print "oooh"
    obj = GETATT_VERIFY()
    print getattr(GETATT_VERIFY, 'name')
    getattr(obj, 'set_value')()
    print obj.value
```

Answer (score 0):

[getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) can access class attributes with **class** and **object**.

For example, there is `Test` class  below:

```py
class Test:
    class_variable = "Class variable"
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_variable = "Instance variable"
    
    def instance_method(self, var):
        print(var)
        
    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls, var):
        print(var)
        
    @staticmethod
    def static_method(var):
        print(var)
```

Then, accessing `Test` class attributes with **class** and `getattr()` results as shown below:

```py
print(getattr(Test, "class_variable"))                  # Class variable
print(getattr(Test, "instance_variable"))               # Error

getattr(Test, "instance_method")("Instance method")     # Error
getattr(Test, "instance_method")("", "Instance method") # Instance method
getattr(Test, "class_method")("Class method")           # Class method
getattr(Test, "static_method")("Static method")         # Static method

print(getattr(Test, "my_variable"))                     # Error
print(getattr(Test, "my_variable", "Doesn't exist"))    # Doesn't exist

print(getattr(Test, "my_method")())                     # Error
print(getattr(Test, "my_method", "Doesn't exist")())    # Error
print(getattr(Test, "my_method", "Doesn't exist"))      # Doesn't exist
```

Then, accessing `Test` class attributes with **object** and `getattr()` results as shown below:

```py
obj = Test()
print(getattr(obj, "class_variable"))                  # Class variable
print(getattr(obj, "instance_variable"))               # Instance variable

getattr(obj, "instance_method")("Instance method")     # Instance method
getattr(obj, "instance_method")("", "Instance method") # Error
getattr(obj, "class_method")("Class method")           # Class method
getattr(obj, "static_method")("Static method")         # Static method

print(getattr(obj, "my_variable"))                     # Error
print(getattr(obj, "my_variable", "Doesn't exist"))    # Doesn't exist

print(getattr(obj, "my_method")())                     # Error
print(getattr(obj, "my_method", "Doesn't exist")())    # Error
print(getattr(obj, "my_method", "Doesn't exist"))      # Doesn't exist
```