# Python - passing a function as an argument to another function

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing, argument-passing

I have two files;

1. The first file, `myProgram.py`, is a python file with a number of functions
   one of the functions contained inside is `myFunction`
   this function would be called with

   ```
   import myProgram
   myProgram.thisFunction()
   myProgram.thatFunction()
   ```
2. The second file contains a menu system, with calls to the functions in `myProgram.py`

I'd like to call a particular function based on an argument passed to a function in file2

```
def file2_function(function):
    myProgram.function

file2_function(thisFunction(x,y,z))
```

which would essentially create myProgram.thisfunction(x,y,z) and execute it.

I guess I could do this using a bunch of if/elif statements, say:

```
def file2_function(function):
    if function == 1:
        myProgram.thisFunction
    elif function == 2: 
        myProgram.thatFunction
```

Though that could get messy as I'm already using a lot of if/elif/else statements for the menu system.

Is there a better way (or is the if/elif route the way to go?)

Comment: It's not clear why you need this `file2_function` in the first place. Why cannot you call `myProgram.whatever` directly?

Comment: Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: with so many answers in a short space of time it's hard to decide who to give the answer to - getattr seems to be the easiest to maintain though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you have `getattr`. See following snippet:

```
>>> import sys
>>> getattr(sys,'exc_info')
<built-in function exc_info>
>>> getattr(sys,'exc_info')()
(None, None, None)
```

Comment: downvoter, any comments, please :) there are reasons under this solution, I am pretty sure OP wants call functions by names

Comment: Didn't downvote but fail to see how `sys.modules` is helpful in this case. `getattr` is, of course...

Comment: overkill, yep, i primarily thought of `sys.modules['__builtin__']`

Comment: The question is asking about how to pass a function as a parameter. Your solution could be almost functionally equivalent but misses the gist of the question.

Answer (score 4):

The `*args` in the function `file2_function` means the arguments to be passed to the function in which it calls:

```
def func1(a):
    print a

def file2_function(function,*args):
    function(*args)

file2_function(func1,4)
#4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a dictionary where key is the name of the function, and value is the function itself. Short example:

```
functions = { 'add' : lambda x,y : x + y, 'mult': lambda x,y : x * y, 'div' : lambda x,y : x / y, 'sub' : lambda x,y : x - y  }
functions['add'](1,2) # returns 3
```

Comment: Two downvotes in a row. Could you guys explain me what's wrong with the dictionary-based approach so I could correct my answer?

Answer (score 2):

@aga gave you a good hint. When I'm writing cli applications I usually do smth like:

```
def func1():
    pass

def func2():
    pass

def func3():
    pass

def func_caller(name):
    func_dict = {
        'func1': func1,
        'func2': func2,
        'func3': func3
        }
    try:
        func_dict[name]()
    except KeyError:
        print "no such func"
```

Comment: for imported functions it is pretty easy to write smth similar with `__all__`, `import *`, and `func.__name__`

Comment: +1; when checking only for equality and you are just deciding which function to call, a dictionary is perfect for looking that function up.

Comment: I actually upvoted, but there is a maintenance problem with coded dictionary approach, when you add or modify a function, you have to reflet this in dict, prone to errors. general solutions, such as django commands mechanism is looks more promizing for me.

Comment: @alko yes, you are right. it really depends on the system you are coding. Django commands work with only `handle` method. all the logic to process input data is on a developer. sometimes it is pretty useful to look at interfaces(I know there are no interfaces in Python, I mean a concept of interfaces) and design patterns.