# Apply numpy function based on string

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to apply a numpy function based on a string ?
If I give 'max' call np.max.

```
values = np.array([[1,2,-1],[2,3,6], [0,-1,4]]) 
aggregator = 'max'
print np.max(values, axis=0)
>>> [2 3 6]
```

What I hope is something like this :

```
some_cool_function(aggregator, values, axis=0)
>>> [2 3 6]
```

This will give a better readability and shorten my code. Instead of doing multiple if.

**EDIT** :

I found the [numpy.apply_along_axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) but it expects a function, it can't be a string.

Comment: How about wrapping the **multiple if** in `some_cool_function`? What's wrong with that?

Comment: Maybe learning something new and not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`getattr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075190/1916449):

```
>>> getattr(np, 'max')(values, axis=0)
array([2, 3, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `np.apply_along_axis()`. Examples:

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(np.max, 0, values)
array([2, 3, 6])

>>> np.apply_along_axis(np.min, 1, values)
array([-1,  2, -1])
```

EDIT:
If you *really* want to use strings, you can just make a dictionary mapping your strings to functions (e.g. `{'max':np.max, 'min':np.min}`) and then wrap the whole thing in a two line `super_cool_function`.