# Django query update - the field is determined by a string

Tags: django, string, django-queryset

I want to update a record, but the field is determined by string. Is it possible to do so?

This is my model:

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    wallet1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    wallet2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

This is my code:

```
amount = 200
transfer_from = 'wallet1'
transfer_to = 'wallet2'

obj = Wallet.objects.get(user_id=1)
obj.transfer_from = obj.transfer_from - amount
obj.transfer_to = obj.transfer_to + amount
obj.save()
```

Django only recognize the field when i write this:

```
obj.wallet1 = obj.wallet1 - amount
```

but it doesn't recognize this:

```
transfer_from = 'wallet1'
obj.transfer_from = obj.transfer_from - amount
```

Is said 'Wallet' object has no attribute 'transfer_from'. Thank you.

Comment: First of all, wallet1 is field of class Wallet and 'wallet1' is a string. How do you expect Django to understand that by string 'wallet1' you actually are referring to wallet1 of Wallet. Plus, its obvious that you get object has no attribute error. Also, whats wrong with obj.wallet1 = obj.wallet1 - amount

Comment: You should use setattr and getattr.
 setattr(obj, field_obj, value)

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar i do that because i get the 'wallet1' from my front end with request.data['transfer_from']. So i put the data from front end into a variable.

Comment: @durdenk Can you show me some sample code or a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not tested but should work.

```
amount = 200
transfer_from = 'wallet1'
transfer_to = 'wallet2'


obj = Wallet.objects.get(user_id=1)
transfer_from_field_val = getattr(obj,transfer_from)
transfer_to_field_val = getattr(obj,transfer_to)
transfer_from_field_val = transfer_from_field_val - amount
transfer_to_field_val = transfer_to_field_val + amount

setattr(obj , transfer_from, transfer_from_field_val)
setattr(obj , transfer_to, transfer_to_field_val)
obj.save()
```

Comment: the getattr is working, but unfortunately the setattr doesn't work. do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is a Python question.
Please refer to this: [What is getattr() exactly and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Using `getattr`, here is what you could do:

```
transfer_from_label = 'wallet1'
transfer_from = getattr(obj, transfer_from_label)
transfer_from = transfer_from - amount
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setattr(obj, transfer_form, getattr(obj, transfer_form) - amount)
```

[getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).