# Access Instance of scrapy pipeline class

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I want to access the variable `self.cursor` to make use of the active postgreSQL connection, but i am unable to figure out how to access the scrapy's instance of the pipeline class.

```
class ScrapenewsPipeline(object):

  def open_spider(self, spider):
      self.connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host= os.environ['HOST_NAME'],
        user=os.environ['USERNAME'],
        database=os.environ['DATABASE_NAME'],
        password=os.environ['PASSWORD'])
      self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
      self.connection.set_session(autocommit=True)


  def close_spider(self, spider):
      self.cursor.close()
      self.connection.close() 


  def process_item(self, item, spider):
      print ("Some Magic Happens Here")


  def checkUrlExist(self, item):
      print("I want to call this function from my spider to access the 
    self.cursor variable")
```

Please note, i realise i can get access to `process_item` by using `yield item` but that function is doing other stuff and i want access of the connection via `self.cursor` in `checkUrlExist` and be able to call the instance of class from my spiders at will!
Thank you.

Comment: `objectName.cursor`?

Comment: objectName is not known to me, the pipelines class is called when the spider starts automatically, i want to hook an instance to that instance of the class! :)

Comment: Maybe you should consider `getattr` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it#4076099

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access all of your spider class variables by doing `spider.variable_name` here.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "myspider"
        any_variable = "any_value"
```

Your pipeline here

```
class MyPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        spider.any_variable
```

I suggest you to create a connection in your Spider class just like I declared `any_variable` in my example, that will be accessible in your Spider using `self.any_variable` and in your pipelines, it will be accessible via `spider.any_variable`

Comment: I have 60 spiders, in this case all of them with have their own postgreSQL connections, i have only limited RAM because of which this will not prove useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm a little late to the party here but in case any one is looking for the correct answer to this question, any pipeline or middleware (or for that matter, downloader etc.) instance can be accessed through the crawler object which controls everything else. You can access the crawler in a spider by using the `from_crawler` classmethod to set a `.crawler` attribute at the time of initialization.

Doing some digging around in the scrapy shell, you should be able to find the instance of any object being used in the current crawl eg.

1. Spider middlewares `crawler.engine.scraper.spidermw.middlewares`
2. Downloader middlewares `crawler.engine.downloader.middleware.middlewares`
3. Item pipelines `crawler.engine.scraper.itemproc.middlewares` (think so. This is just based on a rudimentary exploration in the scrapy shell)

Please note that I'm not advocating that one should do this for accessing a database connection object from a spider. Just that any Scrapy object instance can be accessed through the crawler object which is the answer to the OP's question as per the title.