# Python Class Attribute Use

Tags: python, class, attributes

I would like to print(use) some attributes of an object instance in the following way. But the code generates an error: 
AttributeError: 'Obj' object has no attribute 'alphabet'

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1

Obj_instance = Obj()

l = ['a', 'b']

for alphabet in l:
    print Obj_instance.alphabet
```

Comment: Use getattr: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it#4076099

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate is pretty poor, IMO. Be sure to read the (currently) [highest-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076099/1126841) instead.

Comment: Use `getattr` to get a method by a string value, `getattr(Obj_instance, alphabet)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @fredtantini said use getattr. Here's an example -

```
class Obj(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.a = 0
    self.b = 1

Obj_instance = Obj()

l = ['a', 'b']

for alphabet in l:
    print getattr(Obj_instance, alphabet)
```