# Using a commandline argument to call a class method

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, methods, arguments

Aplogies if I have the terminology all wrong; I am still learning the basics of Python. I have been unable to google this issue, probably in large part because I don't know the terminology..

So. I have built a class within a .py script with LOTS of methods/functions. To keep this remotely simple, I want to call these from a commandline argument. I have no idea how to explain it, and I can't find anhy examples, so I will try to demo it:

Take for example **mute_on** as the function that I want to call. I run the script with the function/method in the argument, like:

```
python3 ./myscript.py mute_on
```

I assume we'd import sys(?), define the class and the function, and create the relevant object from the class:

```
import sys

class TelnetAVR(PioneerDevice):

    def mute_on(self, mute):
        self.telnet_command("MO")

mypioneer = PioneerDevice('Pioneer AVR', '192.168.2.89', 8102, 10)
```

...and lastly I would like the commandline argument to call the method/function - instead of calling it explicitly like:

```
mypioneer.mute_volume()
```

..I want to use the arg (**sys.argv[1]**) to dynamically call the function, like:

```
mypioneer.{sys.argv[1]}()
```

Any ideas, kind people? I have been auto-referred to [What is getattr() exactly and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it) but I have no idea how that information can help me here.

I have tried setting **cmnd = 'turn_off'** and then the following failed...;

```
getattr(mypioneer, str(cmnd))
getattr(mypioneer, cmnd)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is getattr() exactly and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems a little basic, but I cannot complain as to its efficacy;

```
mypioneer = PioneerDevice('Pioneer AVR', '192.168.2.89', 8102, 10)     
exp = 'mypioneer.' + sys.argv[1] + '()'
print('Executing: ' + exp  )
exec(exp)
```

I gave up loking for a graceful answer, and simply constructed a string that I wanted to execute (exp) based on the commandline argument. Works great.. Home Assistant can use the same script to call 50 telnet controls over my Pioneer AVR.