# Python - use schedule module, using parameters from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr

I'm wish to use the `schedule` module, as shown [here](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/), in a way that code read schedule parameters from a text file, for example:

```
start_day=1,2,3,4
start_time=09:00
```

module's syntax is as follows (wish to change days, and `job`):

```
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
```

my first get was to use `getattr()` - but it is for a more simple uses, such as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Appreciate any help

Comment: I don't understand the question (probably because there is no question). What's wrong with `getattr`? Doesn't it do what you want?

Comment: @Aran-Fey - as far as I understand you can use `getattr` to set one parameter, as shown in example -`getattr(x,'foo')` is identical to `x.foo`, the `schedule` function is constructed of more parameter.

Answer (score 0):

that is what I was looking for:

```
for day, entries in activeSched.iteritems():
                for i, entry in enumerate( entries ):
                    getattr( schedule.every(), day ).at( entry[ 0 ] ).do( setScheduledTemp, entry[ 1 ] )
```