# Is there efficient way to validate many variables with appropriate notice?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
if self.a == "":
    raise MyException("The required parameter 'a' is empty")
if self.b == "":
    raise MyException("The required parameter 'b' is empty")
if self.v == "":
    raise MyException("The required parameter 'v' is empty")
if self.g == "":
    raise MyException("The required parameter 'g' is empty")
if self.quality == "":
    raise MyException("The required parameter 'quality' is empty")
if self.abc == "":
    raise MyException("The required parameter 'abc' is empty")
```

It's seems like too much repeated pattern. The issue is that I can't find a way to make it simpler and compact.

Any ideas?

Comment: [getattr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538330/7311767)

Comment: Lazy solution: don't bother doing any checking at all. If your program crashes later because one of the parameters has a bad value, then mission accomplished -- the program halted and the user knows what the problem is.

Comment: @StephenRauch How would I create the name of the parameter that is missing?

Comment: @Kevin My users aren't programmers. The error appear to the UI must be well written so they will know which setting is missing. I can't show them trace of error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you still want to validate all arguments, here is a solution using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) as suggested above:

```
for attribute in ["a", "b", ...]:
    if getattr(self, attribute) == "":
        raise MyException(f"The required parameter '{attribute}' is empty")
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have ["a", "b", ...]  I have [self.a, self.b]   - self shouldn't be shown in the message

Comment: @Luis `getattr(self, "attribute")` is equivalent to `self.attribute`

Comment: @Luis the message shown will be identical to the ones you have in your question

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advocate for getting really fancy trying to eliminate all redundancy. Your code is easy to understand. Doing something clever with `getattr()` or whatnot to avoid repeating each variable name twice will turn a simple set of `if` statement into something significantly more complicated.

That said, this is one of the rare times where compacting the code is worth it:

```
if self.a == "":       raise MyException("The required parameter 'a' is empty")
if self.b == "":       raise MyException("The required parameter 'b' is empty")
if self.v == "":       raise MyException("The required parameter 'v' is empty")
if self.g == "":       raise MyException("The required parameter 'g' is empty")
if self.quality == "": raise MyException("The required parameter 'quality' is empty")
if self.abc == "":     raise MyException("The required parameter 'abc' is empty")
```

You could extract an exception raising method out of it; particularly valuable if you do this type of validation in many other places.

```
def requireNonEmpty(value, name):
    if value == "":
        raise MyException("The required parameter '{}' is empty".format(name))

requireNonEmpty(self.a, 'a')
requireNonEmpty(self.b, 'b')
requireNonEmpty(self.v, 'v')
requireNonEmpty(self.g, 'g')
requireNonEmpty(self.quality, 'quality')
requireNonEmpty(self.abc, 'abc')
```