# Accessing variable field/column in a raw

Tags: sqlite, web2py

I like to access variable columns/fields of a row in SQL, how can it be done?
For example, in web2py x = db(db.table.name=="john").select().last().job1 will give you the job field of the row where name equal "john". But let's say I want to choose other field/column for x in another condition like

```
if conditon1:
  column = job1
if condition2: 
  column = job2
x = db(db.table.name=="john").select().last().column
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` objects can be [accessed like dictionaries](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#select), so you can do:

```
x = db(db.table.name=="john").select().last()[column]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in python [getattr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it) function

```
if conditon1:
  column = "job1"
if condition2: 
  column = "job2"
x = getattr(db(db.table.name=="john").select().last(), column, "Not Found")
```

Comment: Using `gettatr` is not necessary, as `row` objects act as dictionaries. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368173/440323.