# How to call multiple class method with for loop within a function?

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

How can I call multiple class' methods with a for loop in python? Also, How do I fix the AttributeError so that when I have many more methods, I don't have to write conditional statements to call every method one by one? My code is as follows. Thanks

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):

    def method_1(self, key):

    def method_2(self, key):

    def method_3(self):

def process(commands):
    length = len(commands)
    result = []
    stack = Test()

    for command in commands:
        command = command.split()
        if len(command) == 2:
            # Perform stack.method_1 or stack.method_2
            result.append(stack.command[0](command[1])) <====== AttributeError
        else: 
            # Perform stack.method_3
            result.append(stack.command) <===== stack has no attribute command
    return result

commands = ["method_1 5","method_2 9", "method_3", "method_1 2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `getattr` function to access the attribute value of an object

```
for command in commands:
    command = command.split()

    if len(command) == 2:
        # Perform stack.method_1 or stack.method_2
        result.append(getattr(stack, command[0])(command[1]))
    else:
        # Perform stack.method_3
        result.append(getattr(stack, command[0])())
return result
```

[What is getattr() exactly and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it)