# Name of Modules to compute sparsity

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm writing a function that computes the sparsity of the weight matrices of the following fully connected network:

```
class FCN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FCN, self).__init__()

        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)
    
    def forward(self, x):

        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.relu1(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        out = self.relu2(out)
        out = self.fc3(out)
        out = self.relu3(out)
        out = self.fc4(out)

        return out
```

The function I have written is the following:

```
def print_layer_sparsity(model):
    for name,module in model.named_modules():
        if 'fc' in name:
            zeros = 100. * float(torch.sum(model.name.weight == 0))
            tot = float(model.name.weight.nelement())
            print("Sparsity in {}.weight: {:.2f}%".format(name, zeros/tot))
```

But it gives me the following error:

> torch.nn.modules.module.ModuleAttributeError: 'FCN' object has no attribute 'name'

It works fine when I manually enter the name of the layers (e.g.,

> (model.fc1.weight == 0)
> (model.fc2.weight == 0)
> (model.fc3.weight == 0) ....

but I'd like to make it independent from the network. In other words, I'd like to adapt my function in a way that, given any sparse network, it prints the sparsity of every layer. Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
getattr(model, name).weight
```

In place of

```
model.name.weight
```

Your `print_layer_sparsity` function becomes:

```py
def print_layer_sparsity(model):
    for name,module in model.named_modules():
        if 'fc' in name:
            zeros = 100. * float(torch.sum(getattr(model, name).weight == 0))
            tot = float(getattr(model, name).weight.nelement())
            print("Sparsity in {}.weight: {:.2f}%".format(name, zeros/tot))
```

You can't do `model.name` because `name` is a `str`. The in-built `getattr` function allows you to get the member variables / attributes of an object using its name as a string.

For more information, checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it) answer.