# Referencing a class variable in a class function Python

Tags: python, class-variables

```
class dataM:

   a=[]
   b=[]
   c=[]

   def __init__(self):
       self.data=[]
       self.data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(file_Name))
       self.a = self.data['a']
       self.b = self.data['b']
    
   def merge(self, col_name1, col_name2):
       concat=[self.col_name1, self.col_name2]
```

I am trying to reference the value passed in from the function parameter. For example, if the `col_name1` equals 'a' in the merge function, `merge('a', 'b')`, I want the concat list to reference `self.a`.

Comment: see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: Store your lists (a, b, c) in a dictionary so you can simply do `self.lists[col]`

Comment: Perfect! That link helped. thank you