# Using variable to get list from imported module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a script where my zoom classes would auto open based on the schedule.

I made a module named schedule which contains separate lists of each weekday's routine.

In the main file, I made a dictionary where the key is the integer value we get after using datetime.today().weekday() and the value is its corresponding weekday's name such as {0:monday}

In my function, if today's weekday integer value matches with the dictionary key, then it will call its corresponding value weekday from the schedule module. But when I run it, it's saying " AttributeError: module 'schedule' has no attribute 'value' "

Here's part of my code for reference

```
#Monday=0, Tuesday=1 , Wednesday=2, Thursday=3, Sun=6.
weekday = {'1':'tuesday',
       '2':'wednesday',
       '3':'thursday',
       '6':'sunday',
       '0':'monday'}
#Function for opening and closing link in webbrowser.
def open_webbrowser():
global activation
day = datetime.today().weekday()
for key, value in weekday.items():
    if int(key) == day:
        for i in schedule.value:...
```

And here's the schedule module. I replaced the original links with 'zoomlink'

```
#Class routine.
sunday = [
[zoomlink,'09:01','09:39'],
[zoomlink,'10:01','10:39'],
[zoomlink,'11:01','11:39'],
[zoomlink,'12:01','12:39']
]
monday = [...]
tuesday = [...]
wednesday = [...]
thursday = [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

for the below part,

```py
for i in schedule.value:...
```

replace with,

```py
for i in getattr(schedule, value):...
```

It should work. Here is the reason, in the for loop you'll get `value` as `tuesday`, `wednesday`, `thursday`, `sunday` or `monday` and it's a string. So if you access it like `schedule.tuesday`, definitely it should be worked. But unfortunately, you are accessing `schedule.value` and the `value` also a variable and there is no attribute called `value` in schedule module. So one of the easiest and more pythonic solutions is to use [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). I took below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55609455/6194097) from [What is getattr() exactly and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075190/6194097) the question.

> getattr(object, 'x') is completely equivalent to object.x.
>
> There are only two cases where getattr can be useful.
>
> - you can't write object.x, because you don't know in advance which attribute you want (it comes from a string). Very useful for meta-programming.
> - you want to provide a default value. object.y will raise an AttributeError if there's no y. But getattr(object, 'y', 5) will return 5.

Now you'll get a better understanding to use the [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function and for more information check the official documentation or the question that I've mentioned earlier.

Comment: You're welcome @m4rk_Henry_ftw, just updated my answer to know more about what you did wrong and this the pythonic way to solve such a situation. If you didn't get any point or if you need anything to know don't hesitate to comment below, happy to help you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working is because `schedule.value` tries to get a variable called `value` in the schedule module, when you meant for it to expand to something like `schedule.sunday`.

One way you can fix this is by encapsulating your lists in a dictionary, where you can access the lists with a string index such as "sunday" or "monday". If you were to do this, your schedule module would look something like this:

```
zoomLinkData = {
    "sunday": [
        [zoomlink,'09:01','09:39'],
        [zoomlink,'10:01','10:39'],
        [zoomlink,'11:01','11:39'],
        [zoomlink,'12:01','12:39']
    ],
    "monday": [...],
    "...": [...]
}
```

In order to access the data in this dictionary in your loop, you could do this:

```
for key, value in weekday.items():
    if int(key) == day:
        for i in schedule.zoomLinkData[value]:...
```