# How can I access Json attribute and check if (key)exist in payload or not using python

Tags: python

[This is my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14IiB.png)

End user can able to update **Summary** or **my_story** one at a time, This is my endpoint URL  **http:localhost:3000/api/account/profile**, once user update any one of the field, the URL will work

[This is Request payload for **summary** field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TLr4.png)

If the user update the **Summary** field the above endpoint URL will work.

[This is Request payload for **my_story** field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKG6l.png)

If the user update the **my_story** field the above endpoint URL will work.

My code(Once the user update anyone of the field. I want to check which field is updated, for this how can I check whether the user is updated **Summary** or **my_story**,after accessing the field I want to sanitize the field and send it to response below one is my code):

```
from lxml.html import clean
def account_update():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    cleaner = clean.Cleaner()
    if data['other_details']['summary']:
        clean_overview = (data['other_details']['summary'])
        sanitized_html = cleaner.clean_html(clean_overview)
    else:
        clean_overview = (data['other_details']['my_story'])
        sanitized_html = cleaner.clean_html(clean_overview)
    return jsonify({"account": data})
```

Guys , in the above code I am getting the request payload as data, after that I am accessing the **summary** and **my_story** fields as data['other_details']['summary'] and data['other_details']['summary'], here I wrote if condition to check if the user update **summary** field if condition will work suppose user update **my_story** field it will goes to else part, but in my case if I update **my_story** field getting error.

**Error:**
if data['other_details']['summary']:

KeyError: 'summary'

**NOTE:**

Sanitizing the field is working fine (I mean cleaner = clean.Cleaner() and sanitized_html = cleaner.clean_html(clean_overview), I just want to know which field the user is updating. Please help me guys.

Comment: check for the key before accessing it or wrap it in a try except block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the `request.data` doesn't always have the `summary` field in `data['other_details']`.

This means, you have to check for it in you `if`-`else` block before trying to access it.

Best to check for `other_details` as well.

Here is one way of doing this:

```python
from lxml.html import clean

def account_update():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    cleaner = clean.Cleaner()
    if 'other_details' in data:
        other_details = data['other_details']

        if 'summary' in other_details:
            clean_overview = other_details['summary']
            sanitized_html = cleaner.clean_html(clean_overview)

        elif 'my_story' in other_details:
            clean_overview = other_details['my_story']
            sanitized_html = cleaner.clean_html(clean_overview)

    return jsonify({"account": data})
```

Answer (score 0):

What i see your program just can't find summary atribute.

#### Solution 1

Im not sure this will work but function **getattr()** can help you.
Change this line

```
data['other_details']['summary']
```

To this

```
getattr(getattr(data,'other_details'),'summary', False)
```

Here you can learn more about getattr()
*[What is getattr() exactly and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it)*

#### Solution 2

Just use some `try:` and `except:`