# Django Check is a Model Field has chocies defined or not

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model

```
class StudentEfficacy(models.Model):
    class FatherEducation(models.IntegerChoices):
        NoEducation = 0, _("No Education")
        PrimaryEducation = 1, _("Primary Education")
        SecondaryEducation = 2, _("Secondary Education")
        GraduateStudy = 3, _("Graduate Study")
        PostGraduateStudy = 4, _("Post Graduate Study")
        DoctorOfPhilosophy = 5, _("Doctor of Philosophy")

    student_efficacy_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    father_education = models.IntegerField(choices=FatherEducation.choices)
    study_time = models.IntegerField("Study Time in mins")
```

I want to dynamically check if the field has `choices` defined.

for example I want to do something like below:

```
stud = StudentEfficacy.objects.get(pk=1)
if stud.father_education has choices defined:
   print(stud.father_education)
elif not stud.study_time has choices defined:
   print(stud.study_time)  ​
```

Actually in the example above I have given fixed models and fields but actual use would be like below:

```
for model_inst in models_list:
    for field in model_field_list[model_inst._meta.verbose_name]
        if getattr(model_inst, field) has choices defined:
            print("Something")
        else:
            print("Something else")  ​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the fields definition from the `_meta` attribute of the model class. This attribute has the method `get_field` which will get the field for you. The field then would have the attribute `choices` which you can check:

```
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist


try:
    if model._meta.get_field(field).choices is not None:
        print("Something")
    else:
        print("Something else")
except FieldDoesNotExist:
    print("Non-existent field")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found a workaround form here : [How to use getattr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it)

```
for model_inst in models_list:
    for field in model_field_list[model_inst._meta.verbose_name]
        if getattr(model_inst, f'get_{field}_display', False):
            print("Something")
        else:
            print("Something else")
```

PS: Looking for better answers

**EDIT 1:**

definitely recommend this [answer by Abdul Aziz Barkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67102388/django-check-is-a-model-field-has-chocies-defined-or-not/67102563#67102563)