# Pass SQLAlchemy table column to Flask route during search

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I am rather new to Flask and web development in general and am struggling to figure out how to set up arbitrary column searching.

My form:

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    choices = [('facilityid', 'facilityid'),
               ('facilityname', 'facilityname'),
               ('networkid', 'networkid'),
               ('contractid', 'contractid'),
               ('address', 'address')]
    select = SelectField('Search for something', choices=choices)
    id_search = StringField('')
    submit = SubmitField('Search')
```

My Route:

```
@app.route('/results')
def results(search):
    search_string = search.data['id_search']
    search_field = search.data['select']

    # TODO: Remove redundant code
    if search_string == '':
        query = FGymNetworkFacilities.query.order_by(func.rand()).offset(20).limit(10).all()
        table = FacilityTable(query)
        table.border = True
    elif search_field == 'address' and search_field != '':
        query = FGymNetworkFacilities.query.filter(FGymNetworkFacilities.address.like(f'%{search_string}%')).all()
        table = FacilityTable(query)
        table.border = True

    if not results:
        flash('no results!')
        return redirect('/')

    return render_template('facilities.html', table=table)
```

This table model has around 80 columns and I'd like to not make 80 `if/else` statements. I need to find a way to pass the column name to the line (in this example `address`)

`query = FGymNetworkFacilities.query.filter(FGymNetworkFacilities.address.like(f'%{search_string}%')).all()`

But if there is a better way to do this, I'm definitely open to that. Unfortunately Elastic Search is not something I can implement given the constraints of this project and am forced to use this type of search method for now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Use `getattr()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076099/6560549), e.g., `search_col = getattr(FGymNetworkFacilities, search_field)`.

Comment: On a side note: `elif search_field == 'address' and search_field != '':` is unnecessarily complex. `elif search_field == 'address':` will always have the same boolean outcome.