# How to add pandas series operation as a parameter for another function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a function which would add certain operation on the pandas series.
for eg lets say we have this dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_info(df, series, func):
return df[Series].func

data = np.random.randint(10, size= (3, 4))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])


    a   b   c   d
0   3   1   3   7
1   6   8   8   3
2   9   4   4   9
```

Here the mean of the 'd' series is df.d.mean() = 6.3.

Instead I want to use my function:
`mn = get_info(df, 'd', mean())`

But it runs into error NameError: name 'mean' is not defined

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Just in case if you want to read more about [`getattr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075190/12416453)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can do, explanation in the comments:

```
def get_info(df, series, func):
    # check if the method is implemented
    if hasattr(df[series], func):
        # get the method
        f = getattr(df[series], func)
        # check if the method is callable
        if callable(f):
            # call the method
            return f()
        else:
            return "Method is not callable"
    else:
        return "Method is not implemented"

# example usage
get_info(df, 'd', 'mean')
```