# Programmatically / Dynamically concatenate parameters to an object to access data

Tags: python, oop, dynamic, properties

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
class child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.figure = "Square"
        self.color = "Green"

bot = child()
bot_parameters = ['color', 'figure'] 

[print(bot.i) for i in bot_parameters] #Attribute Error from the print function.
```

I know I can access the parameter values with `__dict__` but I wanted to know if it is possible to concatenate the parameters to programmatically/dynamically get the values.

Comment: You can also use `getattr()` as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: it is unclear what you expect to achieve. What should be the value for `size` which is indeed not defined? It's unclear what you mean by _concatenate the parameters to programatically/Dynamically get the values_

Comment: for example i can write the code: 
print(bot.figure)
print(bot.color)
But my question is if its possible to do something like:
for parameter in ['figure', 'color']:
     print(bot.parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) and [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) functions together and retrieve the class instance's attributes dynamically like this:

```
class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.figure = "Square"
        self.color = "Green"

bot = Child()

print([getattr(bot, attrname) for attrname in vars(bot)])  # -> ['Square', 'Green']
```

You *could* also just hardcode `['figure', 'color']`, but that's not as "dynamic" and would have to be updated whenever the class' attributes were changed.

Comment: Wouldn't dot dict get similar results? `bot.__dict__`?

Comment: @ybressler_simon: In this case, "yes". `vars()` is more generic and works with objects other than class instances. Also in this case it's less typing and better conveys the intent IMO.

Comment: fair! will look for use cases in my curr work for `vars()` :)

Comment: @ybressler_simon: Also note that there are other things in `__dict__` besides the attributes (which you will have to skip or filter-out some way).