# Iterating through list elements and apply to class

Tags: python, class

I'm looking to establish a list, (`list_=[a,b,c]`), iterate over the list and apply it to a class (`class_`). So something like this:

```
for letter in list_:
     x = class_.letter
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "apply it to a class"? Are you looking for [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)?

Comment: `getattr(class_, letter)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are typically accessed from a class using a `dot` notation, ex: `my_class.attribute_1`. This is useful when accessing attributes are hard coded.

But as you point out, this is not useful when needing to dynamically access attributes, as in the case of the list above. The solution in these cases is to access attributes using the `getattr()` method which takes input of your class and the attribute name. Ex: `x = 'attribute_1`, `getattr(my_class, x)` would return the same results as `my_class.attribute_1`.

It is worth pointing out that attributes can be set in a similar way: `my_class.foo = 1` is equivalent to `setattr(my_class, 'foo', 1)`.

**Here is a solution where attributes are accessed using a list (from an example class):**

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

# Instantiate your class
my_class = MyClass()

# Create a list of letters
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# Get attributes
for letter in list_1:
    x = getattr(my_class, letter)
    print(f'{letter=}, {x=}')
```

Comment: Noted. And improved answer @martineau

Comment: It's also possible to dynamically get a list of the attributes via the built-in [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) function instead of hardcoding them like that. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70808540/355230) to [Programmatically / Dynamically concatenate parameters to an object to access data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807561/programmatically-dynamically-concatenate-parameters-to-an-object-to-access-dat) for an example.

Comment: Neat! I started a thread on your answer there @martineau