# What is the 'correct' way to alter one element from a list attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr, setattr

Consider the following piece of code

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Widget:
    def __init__(self, low=None, mid=None, high=None):
        self.low = low
        self.mid = mid
        self.high = high

widget = Widget(low=[Point(0, 1), Point(1, 2), Point(2, 3)],
                mid=[Point(3, 4), Point(4, 5), Point(5, 6)],
                high=[Point(6, 7), Point(7, 8), Point(8, 9)])

a, b, c = Point(11, 11), Point(12, 12), Point(13, 13)
```

Now I would like to alter the attributes of the widget instance. Each attribute has to be altered in a certain way. Specifically, let us consider the (simplified) example where the first element of `widget.low` needs to be set to `a`, the second element of `widget.mid` to `b` and the last element of `widget.high` to `c`. Since these operations are very similar I am tempted to write it in a nested fashion like so,

```
for attr, ix, value in (('low', 0, a), ('mid', 1, b), ('high', 2, c):
    getattr(widget, attr)[ix] = value
```

Now, this feels very naughty. Because, I am using `getattr` to set (part of) an attribute. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it) the first answer states that setting attributes should be done by `setattr`. The above construction would then become something like,

```
for attr, ix, value in (('low', 0, a), ('mid', 1, b), ('high', 2, c):
    setattr(widget, attr, getattr(widget, attr)[:ix] + [value] + getattr(widget, attr)[ix+1:])
```

Wow! That is really ugly. I believe the result of these two loops is the same, for instance, as expected `self.mid = [Point(3,4), Point(12, 12), Point(5,6)]` . I am interested in the 'correct' (most pythonic) way to do this? I know 'flat is better than nested' and for this task I could write out three lines. But I am considering a situation where nesting can save a significant amount of duplication. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: _setting attributes should be done by `setattr`_: Yes, but you _aren't_ setting an attribute. You're _modifying_ an element of the attribute, but the value of the attribute  itself remains unchanged. There's nothing wrong with `getattr(widget, attr)[ix] = value`, but unless you have a whole lot of attributes that need to be changed, I would just explicitly write out those lines: `self.low[0] = a; self.mid[1] = b; self.high[-1] = c`

Comment: Also, the result of both your loops is _not_ the same. In the first case, it _modifies_ the lists in-place, so if you have `somelist = [Point(...), ...]` and then use that as `widget = Widget(somelist, ...)`, then modifying `widget.low` will also modify `somelist`. In the second case, `widget.low` is set to a _completely new list_ which is created by stitching together the old list with the new value, and `somelist` would remain unchanged.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, thanks for your answer/comment. My brain was equating any modification to 'setting', thanks for straightening me out. I did know that the two loops do not exactly do the same thing, next time I will be more cautious before I will use the word 'same' on the stack :)