# How to get numerous attributes from a module when looping?

Tags: python, loops, module, syntax, attributes

I am trying to get a list of attributes from any module, that are contained in a list. My problem really is a **syntax problem** : I do not know how the python langage is **intended to be written** in order to solve my problem.

Here is an exemple of the intuitive way I would write it :

```
import numpy

module = numpy
list_attributes = ['__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']

for attribute in list_attributes:
   print(module.attribute)
```

Of course, this is not the only application such a syntax could have: I am only presenting the most *trivial* one to make sure I stay as clear as possible.

Does anyone know how to do what I am trying to do? Or even know if it is feasible in python?

Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: Maybe try `module[attribute]`?

Comment: Unfortunately this syntax is not accepted by python either...

Comment: `print(getattr(module, attribute))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075190/202168

Comment: Thank you very much! On the other hand, this method allows to access only the instantiation of a pure attribute and not that of a method. For example, I can’t create n-arrays (using empty, ones, zeros, etc.) with getattr(). I probably misspoke in my original question.