# Python: pass a class-function as a reference to an external function

Tags: python, oop

I have a class with several functions.
From outside that class, I want to specify with a reference which function to call - but I'm not sure how.

For example, I have an `Animal` class with two functions `sound` and `food`. I want to write a `Zoo` class which receives one of the `Animal`'s functions as input and applies that function to every animal instance it holds (the function **`all_animals_features`**).

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, sound, food):
        self.my_sound = sound
        self.my_food = food

    def sound(self):
        # Do some complicated stuff....
        return self.my_sound

    def food(self):
        return self.my_food


class Zoo():
    def __init__(self, animals):
        self.animals = animals

    def all_animals_features(self, f):
        return [animal.f() for animal in self.animals]

dog = Animal('Woof', 'Bone')
cat = Animal('Meow', 'Cream')
zoo = Zoo([cat, dog])
zoo.all_animals_features(Animal.sound)
```

But of course, `'Animal' object has no attribute 'f'`.

Any idea how can this be implemented?

---

Clarification: if all that is needed, as demonstrated by this silly example, is just getting an attribute then it may be simpler to use [getattr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case you just need to adjust the way the method is called:

```py
class Zoo():
    def __init__(self, animals):
        self.animals = animals

    def all_animals_features(self, f):
        return [f(animal) for animal in self.animals]

dog = Animal('Woof', 'Bone')
cat = Animal('Meow', 'Cream')
zoo = Zoo([cat, dog])
print(zoo.all_animals_features(Animal.sound))
```

Output:

```
['Meow', 'Woof']
```

Since you supply `Animal.sound`, as parameter `f`, the call in the list comprehension is: `f(animal)`