# How to pass data to the method

Tags: php, oop, methods

I pass the data to the Index method, but how to pass if the method is call like that ?

```
if (method_exists($controller,  $method)) {
    $controller->{$method}($controller);
} else {
    $controller->Index('test');
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771036/php-equivalent-of-send-and-getattr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) instead.

Example:

```
call_user_func_array(array($obj, 'some_func'), array('a', 'b'));
```

The above code will call a method named `some_func` from the object `$obj` with 2 parameters `'a'` and `'b'`